# Repeat a function maximum of 3 times

Tags: python

So, i have this code:

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('Age: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid valid. Try again.")
        continue

    if age >= 18:
        print("You are a grown up!")
    else:
        print("You are a child!")

    break
```

What changes should I made, so i can insert an variabile which is different from integer, maximum 3 times, and only after that, will appear "Invalid valid. Try again"

I wrote this code

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('Age: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid valid. Try again.")
        print( "Out of tries! ")
        break

    if age >= 18:
        print("You are a grown up!")
    else:
        print("You are a child!")

    break
```

But this one stops after only 1 try. I Need like 3 tries and only after that, the program will stop.

Comment: Why use a loop if you're going to use break on any condition?

Comment: @OneCricketeer OP is confused about how to break the loop on a specific iteration; the second version of their code doesn't actually do what they want, which is why they're asking for help.  :)

Comment: @Samwise Sure, but the second attempt should be adding a counter, not just ending the loop immediately

Comment: Yes, that is what OP is asking for help with.  We always encourage people to post their non-working code so we can see what they've tried; we should not be surprised when the code does not work.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using for loop instead of a while loop.

**Using For Loop:**

```
max_tries = 3
for _ in range(max_tries):
    try:
        age = input('Age: ')
        if not age.isdigit():
            raise ValueError("Invalid value. Must be an integer.")
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        if age >= 18:
            print("You are a grown up!")
        else:
            print("You are a child!")
        break
else:
    print("Out of tries!")
```

It's also possible to achieve this using while loop like below.

**Using While Loop:**

```
max_tries = 3
tries = 0
while tries < max_tries:
    try:
        age = input('Age: ')
        if not age.isdigit():
            raise ValueError("Invalid value. Must be an integer.")
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        tries += 1
    else:
        if age >= 18:
            print("You are a grown up!")
        else:
            print("You are a child!")
        break

if tries == max_tries:
    print("Out of tries!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a `for` loop that's identical in structure to your `while` loop.  You can use an `else` block to print a special message if the loop is exhausted (i.e. you've gone through all 3 tries) without hitting the `break` that indicates a successful completion:

```
for _ in range(3):
    try:
        age = int(input('Age: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid value. Try again.")
        continue

    if age >= 18:
        print("You are a grown up!")
    else:
        print("You are a child!")

    break
else:
    print("Out of tries!")
```